# ADB "install-multiple" Unknown command: install-multiple

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to simply install a multi-apk app on my non-rooted Samsung tablet via ADB, I think I'm not doing something right.

I first made sure my device was connected/authorized when using ADB. Then, I successfully pushed the apks to `/sdcard/`:

```
adb push E:\PopupFactory2\. /sdcard/
```

Then, I tried installing using `-r` and `-d` switches *(to install an older version of an existing app on my tablet without deleting it's respective appdata)*.. which produces an error:

```
adb shell pm install-multiple -r -d /sdcard/com.rhyshan.popupfactory2.apk /sdcard/config.en.apk
```

**Unknown command: install-multiple**

I know `install-multiple` is a valid command for my ADB runtime; as its listed in the help text when I just type "ADB". Is my syntax wrong?  Everything I read online suggests I'm using the right syntax.

Is there a better way for me to downgrade an existing app (with multiple apk's) to an older version without deleting its respective appdata?  I also have a packaged apkx as well.

Comment: What phone (manufacturer, model name and Android version) do you use?

Comment: @Robert thanks for replying back.  I actually figured out what I was doing wrong. The paths to the respective apk's are supposed to be local on the PC where ADB is executed, I.E., `adb shell pm install-multiple -r -d E:\MyPC\com.rhyshan.popupfactory2.apk E:\MyPC\config.en.apk`.

Comment: If you use `adb shell pm` you can not make use of files on your PC, only files on the phone can be used. So you first have to `adb push` them onto the phone. And then use the path on the phone.